# Printing with Silverlight 5 maximum retry count has been exceeded error

Tags: silverlight, wcf-ria-services

I have Silverlight application with WCF RIA services, periodically when i print document i have error "maximum retry count has been exceeded error".
I'm using basic Http binding and can't set "reliabilitySession inactivityTimeout".
I would tried using net.tcp binding,but in this moment there in no time for this and i'm not even sure that WCF RIA would work with net.tcp.
Is there any solution for this problem.

Answer (score -1):

I solved the problem,funny but when my column was "null" or string.empty i could't print,but i could see preview.

If column is null I replaced it with " " and it works